# Bypass akamai when making request to login. it is working in cURL but not in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, web-scraping

So I'm trying to bypass the akamai bot manager, I have the right config for most of the API endpoints but I can't get this one right.
The weird thing is that when I'm making the request with cURL it is successful but the exact same request in node with Axios and I get halted.

```
data: {
      edge_error: 'halt',
      ref_id: '18.97711602.1643911324.5be44a0',
      wait: 60,
      feedback: {
        email: true,
        url: '',
        recaptcha: { enabled: false, type: 0, sitekey: '' }
      }
    }
```

Request in cUrl

```
curl 'https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login' \
  -H 'authority: accounts.zalando.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"' \
  -H 'x-csrf-token: ajrmn3mbkzoim6hr78yjge2' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'x-flow-id: 3B2K9b3l-TwJFCSC' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'origin: https://accounts.zalando.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://accounts.zalando.com/authenticate?request=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&ui_locales=pl-PL&sales_channel=ca9d5f22-2a1b-4799-b3b7-83f47c191489' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: bm_sz=FE69CF7D021B7F8186BE202F2B626838~YAAQjQ/dWMEoNKx+AQAAIGq7wA5BB7gCmlKhnKxCqL0xvwBh3RwtNxOwgtZL6x9JeZPqpPgVvv7p/OtS4At5F8EyOjWSHpEecdpmMYv4y+I90IGAZ9VF6pAW/zP0C52MCHjAG8kg/w1vz3gja9WtWxZdpnv/CmvCWoUyUD2zQxNmKalb3/Os9XP+cxaS0XbB97yskyjhHWXp3cGEoLpFYPz6KSddhFJpA2xTt2gMLiN+ZKNoPzcb5UiSMHqTNH3+EqrWt0xdKVUMmUWNOtyBEx9bNS/LNq4pNkS8w1bFTq3bUd7eGwFm9h8Ko0A5zTwF2nyZ/zJAlAfSPzLMUR/+7hQrR0myuOOGrcoZmgMsjAcYdbd5Jg8Tf50objqhpZnwrz0003pisLxHJYwJ9EnWK5HrnvA=~3687218~3552578; csrf-token=ajrmn3mbkzoim6hr78yjge2; _abck=9744BF6DBE01056ECC5325F3E006D217~0~YAAQjQ/dWMwoNKx+AQAA2mu7wAfSsaXQPhI0xYetbioC9i3fRI/uGtJDzFI8LEyaRIgLo7j9wsDJ6hRTnjqxKCErcJgZsAKmPBunH91ySFzOL62MjqCCiqGKhH6SGi9aU773jtRMwcXbcggvYOtt/cyE/f893t0VW7TsTYv0r0cr4+PX0VvPVKdk7+Tu3DInKTwiwCe9nwIsU0p0vtmW+o7XD9NYwZF9rjMmf1MeAAC6Lex0wgkEG61nYHf5ICs7nHX+2fQ/a1r6yF9wddNBwW6uhNE1+9U2/CnVBTssUlA2LvE4cB4hau8JQ2NF3pZjZjm7w1DwMQMCMMHU9UKEIB962a3QZTZyjNQSpNhvLYk7dVG2EJH46K+A4GI1vnC7+YBng8U2Vga0nLglhi0ZfWktAt3DdtwsGUHPKJDv9wzOdn8SlS5dnmuxeQHOzfQAAASFQ95opm4zmYBpuByOAur5~-1~||1-QCrhxtykRc-1-10-1000-2||~1643914521; ak_bmsc=F441D3FF51130BA90D53D62D58D3F0EF~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQjQ/dWNQoNKx+AQAAh227wA4ZW++O17k6LEDlDLliUD2/jEwuo7dIKNEOEaMpfHfqoK5GRM9eB3tMO0jiFkdgzBbaYm9EcFaqGBZTpedm/P63s33I7rj41JrwZ4qVp5py2uUtH2z78wNBSBgbwxsiUjV0swjEykj85FuOjWUSlYuH/VsSn9LvNmoaYbCEXijHF4W0PLk7Tztp78LnBZPvl7ijPg5NVGbq0AMj75sPXVjEs+8+iImK74mjplroh0KZC7TMjnLXkmIKwUMDXEx1BcbuOtGZJsR0PvopziDL9tIIZIR2GebjuyvGPHnr2EvCIwy2Yc0nNuJA7mBD5TsUkIlUwL12ZMsnFLAk/DqcWxTUQOWdK2m+iNffIjUEoaM62MyL0rP/w47tJgOeo047jY+KaJloyfgaVDXIhiV2zt2y9LG8b1vMVI/rsdFoioHs7xiCT95Q08BJNT+0nnQmNdM8q148/rXEXed071EtgEFm1iNwozs3gnmR8Q==; bm_sv=F84F1D389D4750ED91CB28E5AFCA27CC~rbzPO0IHaxxkkYvPkb0s0VmwcdQoGkFb8drn9m89qPogdd4d0oVrKiRK2M27N0+PmNKL7WTv9SbVj/uF7/nQUieevVzBzONbOOzW80XentkiuMToc7od0RO+8H8inWipXzzLxrY09Zst/8oKuCcneC8wVEuS4P+OaEmh/eUVm9c=' \
  --data-raw '{"email":"x.x@gmail.com","secret":"x","request":"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"}' \
  --compressed
```

### Request in node

```
const defaultCiphers = tls.DEFAULT_CIPHERS.split(':');
const shuffledCiphers = [
    defaultCiphers[0],
    // Swap the 2nd & 3rd ciphers:
    defaultCiphers[2],
    defaultCiphers[1],
    ...defaultCiphers.slice(3)
].join(':');
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ ciphers: shuffledCiphers });

const logo = await axios.post('https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login', { email: 'x.x@x.com', secret: 'xxxxx', request: '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' }, {
  httpsAgent,
  headers: {
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    authority: 'accounts.zalando.com',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    accept: 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    origin: 'https://accounts.zalando.com',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-gpc': '1',
    Cookie: 'bm_sz=FE69CF7D021B7F8186BE202F2B626838~YAAQjQ/dWMEoNKx+AQAAIGq7wA5BB7gCmlKhnKxCqL0xvwBh3RwtNxOwgtZL6x9JeZPqpPgVvv7p/OtS4At5F8EyOjWSHpEecdpmMYv4y+I90IGAZ9VF6pAW/zP0C52MCHjAG8kg/w1vz3gja9WtWxZdpnv/CmvCWoUyUD2zQxNmKalb3/Os9XP+cxaS0XbB97yskyjhHWXp3cGEoLpFYPz6KSddhFJpA2xTt2gMLiN+ZKNoPzcb5UiSMHqTNH3+EqrWt0xdKVUMmUWNOtyBEx9bNS/LNq4pNkS8w1bFTq3bUd7eGwFm9h8Ko0A5zTwF2nyZ/zJAlAfSPzLMUR/+7hQrR0myuOOGrcoZmgMsjAcYdbd5Jg8Tf50objqhpZnwrz0003pisLxHJYwJ9EnWK5HrnvA=~3687218~3552578; csrf-token=ajrmn3mbkzoim6hr78yjge2; _abck=9744BF6DBE01056ECC5325F3E006D217~0~YAAQjQ/dWMwoNKx+AQAA2mu7wAfSsaXQPhI0xYetbioC9i3fRI/uGtJDzFI8LEyaRIgLo7j9wsDJ6hRTnjqxKCErcJgZsAKmPBunH91ySFzOL62MjqCCiqGKhH6SGi9aU773jtRMwcXbcggvYOtt/cyE/f893t0VW7TsTYv0r0cr4+PX0VvPVKdk7+Tu3DInKTwiwCe9nwIsU0p0vtmW+o7XD9NYwZF9rjMmf1MeAAC6Lex0wgkEG61nYHf5ICs7nHX+2fQ/a1r6yF9wddNBwW6uhNE1+9U2/CnVBTssUlA2LvE4cB4hau8JQ2NF3pZjZjm7w1DwMQMCMMHU9UKEIB962a3QZTZyjNQSpNhvLYk7dVG2EJH46K+A4GI1vnC7+YBng8U2Vga0nLglhi0ZfWktAt3DdtwsGUHPKJDv9wzOdn8SlS5dnmuxeQHOzfQAAASFQ95opm4zmYBpuByOAur5~-1~||1-QCrhxtykRc-1-10-1000-2||~1643914521; ak_bmsc=F441D3FF51130BA90D53D62D58D3F0EF~000000000000000000000000000000~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; bm_sv=F84F1D389D4750ED91CB28E5AFCA27CC~rbzPO0IHaxxkkYvPkb0s0VmwcdQoGkFb8drn9m89qPogdd4d0oVrKiRK2M27N0+PmNKL7WTv9SbVj/uF7/nQUieevVzBzONbOOzW80XentkiuMToc7od0RO+8H8inWipXzzLxrY09Zst/8oKuCcneC8wVEuS4P+OaEmh/eUVm9c=',
    'x-csrf-token': 'ajrmn3mbkzoim6hr78yjge2',
    'x-flow-id': '3B2K9b3l-TwJFCSC',
    referrerPolicy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    referrer: 'https://accounts.zalando.com/authenticate?request=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&ui_locales=pl-PL&sales_channel=ca9d5f22-2a1b-4799-b3b7-83f47c191489',
  },
});
```

Comment: Cookies seem to be the medium through which a "secret" is exchanged with the server.  Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562016/akamai-sensor-data-generator-for-a-valid-abck-cookie-on-post-request-python